# ui-grid 'renderComplete' event after rendering rows in DOM

Tags: ui-grid

I'm using ui-grid 3.2.1.
Trying for a long time now to find an event that notifies me when rows are rendered in the DOM.
I looked a lot in SO, and in their issues in Github.
My test to see if rows are rendered is basically `$('.ui-grid-row').length > 0`.

I tried `rowsRendered` event, `modifyRows(data)`, all sorts of `$timeout(0)` in almost every spot I could, nothing worked, all callbacks are called when the above jQuery still doesn't have results.

As a last resort I found a very inefficient solution - I `$watch` the `.html()` changes of `.ui-grid-contents-wrapper`, which contains the `.ui-grid-row` elements, and when I find one, I turn off the watcher and call the callback. It's bad but it works.

Note - The rows/columns somtimes contain inner directives which may take some time to render. I don't think it should influence `rowsRendered()` event.

Please, can anybody help with this? 
No support from ui-grid team sadly.

EDIT: 
plunkr that show there are no `.ui-grid-row` in DOM when `rowsRendered()` is called:
https://plnkr.co/edit/8clwC5hkwhAEjvoLZ6vO?p=preview

Comment: please provide a plunker so that we can simulate your error

Comment: added a plunkr to demonstrate (see EDIT in question)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var rows= gridApi.core.getAllVisibleRows(gridApi.grid);
```

inside `rowsRendered` function.